# Populate Combobox with font names

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I want to populate a combobox on a userform with available fonts on a pc, when the userform is initialized. i have written a code for it, but it just gives me an error:

```
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Method 'ListCount' of Object '_CommanBarComboBox' failed
```

Ive tried to modify the i = 1 to i = 0, but it doesnt helped me.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Image3.Visible = False
Image6.Visible = False

Dim FontList
Dim i
CreatePapers.ComboBox1.Clear
Set FontList = Application.CommandBars("Formatting").FindControl(ID:=1728)
For i = 1 To FontList.ListCount
CreatePapers.ComboBox1.AddItem FontList.List(i + 1)
Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

I modified the code, the error is gone, however, nothing is filled into the combobox.

```
 Dim FontList As CommandBarControl
Dim i As Long
Dim Tempbar As CommandBar
CreatePapers.ComboBox1.Clear

On Error Resume Next
Set FontList = Application.CommandBars("Formatting").FindControl(ID:=1728)
 ' If Font control is missing, create a temp CommandBar
    If FontList Is Nothing Then
        Set Tempbar = Application.CommandBars.Add
        Set FontList = Tempbar.Controls.Add(ID:=1728)
   End If
    
For i = 1 To FontList.ListCount
Debug.Print FontList.List(i)
        CreatePapers.ComboBox1.AddItem FontList.List(i)
    Next i
    Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0

'   Delete temp CommandBar if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Tempbar.Delete
```

**EDIT 2:**
Added 2 lines of code into the above modified code as mentioned by T.M. , but it still doesnt fill up the combobox, its just empty.

**EDIT 3:**
Changed some line in the code, but still it doesnt retrieves the fonts. Also the FontList is empty, even after the `If FontList Is Nothing Then` part, where it creates the temporary control bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could shorten initializing into a more readable form by assigning a complete array to the combobox'es `.List` property:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ComboBox1.List = GetFontList()    ' << calling `GetFontList()  
End Sub
```

The array itself is the result of the following function:

```
Option Explicit

Function GetFontList() As Variant
    Dim FontList As CommandBarControl    ' << declare type
    On Error Resume Next                 ' provide for missing font control
    Set FontList = Application.CommandBars("Formatting").FindControl(id:=1728)
    On Error GoTo 0
    'If Font control is missing, create it on a temporary CommandBar
    If FontList Is Nothing Then
        Dim tmpBar As CommandBar
        Set tmpBar = Application.CommandBars.Add
        Set FontList = tmpBar.Controls.Add(id:=1728)
    End If

    Dim tmpList: ReDim tmpList(1 To FontList.ListCount, 1 To 1)
    'Assign fonts to array
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(tmpList)
        tmpList(i, 1) = FontList.List(i)
    Next i
    
    'Delete temporary CommandBar eventually
    On Error Resume Next
    tmpBar.Delete
    'return 2-dim 1-based font array as function result
    GetFontList = tmpList
End Function
```

**Further hints**

*The CommandBarControl items can be addressed by a **one**-based index via*

```
FontList.List(i)
```

*) *The combobox'es 2-dimensional `.List` property is **zero**-based, but accepts also assignment of a **one**-based array (as returned by above function).*

Comment: Ive tried this, but it gives me the same error as i mentioned in my post above.

Comment: a) If you are using `UserForm_Initialize` use the `Me.`-prefix instead of the Userform default name itself. b) add `Debug.Print FontList.List(i)` into the `For i loop` to check if you get the fonts c) You commented "nothing is filled into the combobox": did you click into the combo? - Possibliy it is filled but you didn't say to show the first item `Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0` after the loop.

Comment: Added the `Debug.Print FontList.List(i)` line right after the `For i = 1 To UBound(tmpList)` line, and added the `Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0` line after the `Next i` line, but it still gives me the exact same error.

Comment: ..., but does the code list the fonts into the VB Editor's immediate window, so you'd know at least that you get the fonts? Suggest to add `Stop` into code (press <keybd>F8</keybd> for any further code line step) and see where exactly you get the error (in the edited post you wrote `the error has gone`).

Comment: No, the fonts arent printed into the immediate window. After using the Stop, as you suggested, it seems like the error is right after the code starts, meaning that the Fontlist is nothing, and even after the line `If FontList Is Nothing Then` is the Fontlist empty.

Comment: Can it be a typo (_CommanBarComboBox) ? Is `CreatePapers` the UserForm name? (in the Userform code module behind you should use `Me.ComboBox1`) ... If no result and you know what you are doing, you might prefer using system functions via API calls :-;

Comment: Theres no typos, I just checked every line of code. At the beginning of the code, the `Set Fontlist` always retrieves Nothing, and the next part with `If FontList Is Nothing Then` also sets the FontList to Nothing (as if it didntcreates the commandbar or something), so theres no way of showing me the fonts. I dont know how to use the APIs.

Comment: Kind of baffled... do you get values if you are assigning pseudo-values to your combo? How/from where do you call the UserForm?

Comment: I call the userform from s worksheet, just with a click on a commandbutton. Yes, i can populate the combobox with other strings.

Comment: I'm using Office 365 64bit without problems. Anyway, try to test in VB Editor's immediate window `Debug.Print Application.CommandBars("Formatting").FindControl(ID:=1728).Enabled` and `Debug.Print Application.CommandBars("Formatting").FindControl(ID:=1728).Visible` - do you get `False` perhaps? If so then you might set these two properties to `True` by `Application.CommandBars(...)...= True` firstly.  @TomasPerlecky

Comment: I dont know what happened, but now it suddenly works. I changed absolutely nothing, didnt even tried out your Vb Editors Immediate Window debug. print codes. Now it reads all of the fonts on userform initialize.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a FontList item that does not exist. Your `for-loop` is fine. But, you need to change the line inside to:

`CreatePapers.ComboBox1.AddItem FontList.List(i)`

Accessing index + 1 is reaching outside of the bounds of the list, this is why it's crashing.

Your code should look like:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Image3.Visible = False
Image6.Visible = False
Dim FontList
Dim i
CreatePapers.ComboBox1.Clear
Set FontList = Application.CommandBars("Formatting").FindControl(ID:=1728)
For i = 1 To FontList.ListCount
    CreatePapers.ComboBox1.AddItem FontList.List(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Then your error must come from an empty FontList. Though, I don't see why it would.

Comment: For some reason, no matter what I do, it just doesnt retrieves the fonts to the Fontlist.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the exact same problem. I still do not know why exactly the below error happened:

> Method 'ListCount' of Object '_CommanBarComboBox' failed

But I solved it by activating an empty sheet before running this piece of code.
`Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()`
`Sheet1.Activate`
...followed by the rest of the code mentioned in the first answer.